WIX editor website Dependent drop down menu
Hey guys I need some assistance with a dependent drop down to select a career and which field to choose based on the career picked.
So far I have tried using CMS to filter out the different fields to be selected when a career is picked but it didn't do so just displayed all the fields when a career was selected.
I've currently learned how to create npm from vs studio and GitHub and installed it as a package on wix with coding but still no success in getting the correct field when a career has been picked.
could anyone please offer some assistance and guidance where I'm missing something. I'm only a month learning about wix please be patience with me.
I'm trying get the field drop down to display only the categories selected from the career drop down.
